# Reflecting (or loading dynamically) Asp.NET website from the other server

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, proxy

What would be the best architecture for ASP.NET MVC 4 website that has to be updatable when there is no (maintenance)access to the only server accessible from the Internet?

We have two servers: Server A has Internet access, but where we can't make updates when needed. Server B won't have this problem, but it's behind firewalls and can't be accessed from the Internet.

I have come up with a couple of ideas:

- Run Asp.NET site on server B and build simple proxy to server A and tunnel the traffic. (how?) (cf. WCF routing)
- Somehow dynamically load almost whole site from server B. It's Ok if the very core of the application can't be changed, as long as every sub application can be. Maybe build some maintenance page what provides action to load newest libraries and files from the server?
- Build external updater -software.

Server A is also used by other companies and for example IISRESET is out of question. Application Pool that hosts the application can of course be recycled if needed.

With WPF I would just download the newest binaries and load them dynamically when starting the application, but with Asp.NET and IIS it's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Run Asp.NET site on server B and build simple proxy to server A and tunnel the traffic. (how?)

*Any* HTTP proxy can do this, with a mere handful of clicks or commandline instructions. I wouldn't go any other road.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to run on Server A a WCF service, which can copy whole site files from Server B to Server A (I suppose Server B is available from Server A locally). In this scenario Server B is for updating and WCF service is only for deploying.